# Inline SVG in CSS via Webpack

Tags: svg, webpack

I would like to have SVG's written inline in the CSS. In other projects I did this using https://github.com/haithembelhaj/sass-inline-svg in the grunt task. Works fine and I would like to use this solution in a project (Angular), which is built with Webpack. 
Important is, that i have to change the colors (stroke, fill) via CSS.
Does anyone know if & how I get this in or if not, if there is an equivalent solution as Webpack plugin?